# Is the derivative of the following uniformly convergent series uniformly convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $\{c_n\}$ be a sequence of complex numbers converging to zero.

Let $r \in \mathbb{R}$ with $ 0<r<1$.

We can show that $$f_n =  \sum_{n = -N}^{N}c_n r^{|n|}e^{inx}  $$ converges uniformly over $[-\pi, \pi]$.

This can be done by noting that $\{c_n\}$ is convergent and therefore bounded uniformly. And that  $\sum_{n = -N}^{N}r^{|n|}e^{inx}$ converges uniformly by the Weierstrass M-test, so $\sum_{n = -N}^{N}c_n r^{|n|}e^{inx} $ converges uniformly.

How can we show that the sequence of derivatives $$f'_n =\sum_{n = -N}^{N}inc_n r^{|n|}e^{inx} $$ converges uniformly over $[-\pi, \pi]$?

Is it uniformly convergent?

Comment: Why does your same argument not work? Doesn't $\sum nr^n$ converge for $0<r<1$? But, by the way, you don't know that that necessarily converges to $f'(x)$ for all $x$, do you?

Comment: Ah of course I can use the same argument, silly me, thanks! Right I am trying to prove that I can differentiate term by term, so first I prove uniform convergence.